# Branch Cutting in SVN from Xcode 7.2

Tags: ios, xcode, svn, branching-and-merging, xcode7.2

I am struggling a little bit while cutting a new branch from Xcode 7.2. I have done this using Terminal command "svn copy ...". But in Xcode I have seen an option to cut a new branch. But when I used that I am getting a error message as

> Local, non-commit operations do not take a log message or revision properties (1)

What I am doing wrong? I am depicting the steps I had followed using screenshots.

[image: Image1]

[image: Image2]

[image: Image3]

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a (not-documented?) bug: see [this](https://forums.developer.apple.com/thread/24478). I've the same issues with XCode 7.3. You can try a previous version of XCode to check if it works; I've not tried yet, so I'm trusting the comments in the above link.